# Distributed master-worker architecture simulation design in Java

Tags: java

I need to simulate a system in Java where there is a master and a number of workers. Each worker may process its data locally but needs to communicate the master to read data from other nodes. And workers should work concurrently.

How can I simulate this system? Do I need to start a new thread for every running worker and a master thread? Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it on a single machine then I see two options:

1. Create a master and a worker application (make sure that you can run multiple instances of those). Run one master application and multiple instances of the worker application.
2. Create a single application in which you have a single instance of your `Master` class and multiple instances of your `Worker` class. Let the `Master` run in a separate thread and let each `Worker` run in its own thread too.

So the first option is to run each "node" (master or worker) as a separate process, while the second option is to run each "node" as a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty generic question which is open to many architectural solutions. I'd like to present the one I've used in the past. I used RMI here for ease of remote calls.

All master and slave processes are RMI services. Both master and slaves are spawned using the RMI daemon (RMID) which have the bonus feature of "upping" the services in case one goes down due to a JVM crash or any other "abnormal" reason. RMI services in general work based on an interface which defines the contract between the client and the server. Let's say for e.g. that I have to write a service which solves an equation.

We start off with creating two services: master and slave. Both these services implement/expose the same interface to the client. The only difference would be that the "master" service would be solely responsible for "forking" across work to the different slave agents, getting the response back (or re-arranging them if required) and returning it to the client. The master is a simple RMI service which accepts the list of "equations" and splits them across the different clients. Obviously, the master here has references to all the clients it governs in terms of RMI handle (i.e. communication between master and slaves is again a RMI invocation).

Here again, we have a lot of possibilities of configuring how master "looks up" the slaves but I'm sure you can work it out quite easily. This architecture has the advantage of a grid based solution wherein you are not limited by a single process to do all the work for you and hence gain the resiliency and freedom from monolithic heap sizes for your JVM process.

I really haven't used them but [Rio](http://rio-project.org/overview.html) and [JINI](http://river.apache.org/) is something you should look into if you want to build distributed systems in Java.